# Prevent data loss on app upgrade

Tags: android, mdm

We have developed an Android application and pushing the new installations & updates through MDM (Mobile Device Management, Soti Mobi control). The update sent, silently upgrades the application without user's confirmation. Due to this, if application is in use by the users, is automatically stopped, upgraded & started from the beginning and thus users loose their important changes which they were suppose to send to server.

Is it possible in the mobi control to configure an update with a prompt to the user (similar to what it comes when we manually upgrade to the newer versions' APK)?

OR

Can I override any life cycle method which would be invoked on upgrade event, and if users' changes available I would like to abort the update?

Comment: Is there any MDM expert who can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android MDM protocol (called [Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)) doesn't have API to install/uninstall/upgrade applications.

So, pushing an upgrade isn't build-in Android feature, but rather a feature of Soti Mobicontrol application. I think, it make sense to contact them with this question.